# Calculate the time difference between rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have table called tbl_speed, in it column called time i want to calculate time difference between rows,
could some one help me please.

```
  ID            time
```

319427135 ,       '2013-12-17 **14:14:04'** ,

319427694 ,       '2013-12-17 **14:14:09'** ,

319428523 ,       '2013-12-17 **14:14:15'** ,

319534207 ,       '2013-12-17 **14:28:52'** ,

what i need it just to calculate time not date.

**using mysql Query**

Thank you for help.

Comment: What do you need to use to do this? SQL/C#/Java/C/C++ what is it?

Comment: What do you mean by `time diferrence betwen rows` ? Which exactly rows ? First row and third row, previous row and next row, first row and last row ? Please explain.

Comment: I need sum the difference using mysql query

Comment: SUM and difference are 2 different things.

Comment: Please provide the results that you would like for the data you have provided.

Comment: you can subtract two dates and get a decimal value that represents partial days.  then you can SUM these and get a total elapsed time

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT id,time,
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,
    (SELECT MAX(time) FROM tbl_speed WHERE time< t.time),
    time
  ) secdiff
FROM tbl_speed t
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2e64/33)